# Cannot find FREAK detector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, freak

I am developing some code in OpenCV 2.4 and I want to test the FREAK detector but I get compilation errors. I am including the feature2d.h, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FREAK is included in the OpenCV version 2.4.2, so you cannot use it in your current version as it is not implemented. Download and [install](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) OpenCV2.4.2.